# two divs inside a div do not look aligned correctly

Tags: css

I have a container div and two divs inside it.

I have tried to center align the contents of both divs but for some reason, the 2nd div looks incorrect in relation to the first div.

First inner div aligned like this:

```
.main-text {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
color: red;
top: 20%;
width: 100%;
letter-spacing: .6em;
}
```

Second inner div aligned like this:

```
.down-arrow {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}

.bottom {
color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

Full code with demo of how the 2nd inner div with content "DWN" looks off: http://jsfiddle.net/qbmtap7t/

Not sure what I have done wrong, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `position` and `top` directives of your `.bottom` class to the `.down-arrow` which is the actual container of the bottom text:

```
.down-arrow {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbmtap7t/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use Css selectors : try editing your Css class `.down-arrow` like this :

```
.down-arrow .bottom {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See the demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/qbmtap7t/3/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The style you applied for .bottom, apply it for .down-arrow and it would work. Also, you seem to have a lot of html structure just for a simple link, any specific reason for using a span inside anchor? As a best practice, try to avoid unnecessary markup.